# (Highcharts) Polygon-like shell in polar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am not sure on how to go about this chart here, I tried to make it as close to possible but since there are so many options to tinker with, I am at a loss.

I am trying to do this chart in highcharts.

[image]

So far the closes I get to this kind of chart is the polar chart, here is what I had made.

```
$(function() {
  var data = {
    data  : [1,2,3,4,5,5],
    labels: ['text 1','text 2','text 3','text 4','text 5','text 6']
  };
  var counter = 0
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      polar: true
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Demo Chart'
    },

    pane: {
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: 360
    },

    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 60,
      min: 0,
      max: 360,
      categories: data.labels,
      labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var html;
          html = "<div style='text-align:center'>";
          html += "<p style='margin:0em'>";
          html += data.data[counter];
          html += "</p>";
          html += "<p style='margin:0em'>";
          html += data.labels[counter];
          html += "</p>";
          html += "</div>";
          counter++;
          return html;
        }
      }
    },

    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      labels:{
        enabled: false
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 60
      }
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'area',
      name: '',
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [
        {name:'対話⼒力力',y:1},
        {name:'Test 2',y:2},
        {name:'Test 3',y:3},
        {name:'Test 4',y:4},
        {name:'Test 5',y:5},
        {name:'Test 6',y:5}
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/abarcenas29/pen/MywYGP

Here are my question:

1. How can I insert the 4.3 in the image in dead center of the chart?

Edit: I was able to make the chart look like the image, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set [`yAxis.gridLineInterpolation`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.gridLineInterpolation) to `polygon`

2) You can use separate series with just one point with `x = 0` and `y = 0`. Then use [`series.dataLabels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) to return that value as data-label. Or simply use [`Chart.renderer`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to render text/label there.

Comment: Chart.renderer.text in the manual needs an absolute position http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-text-on-chart/ any idea on how to make it dead center on the graph?

Comment: I would use `chart.panes[0].center`, for example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpddZy